# This patent attempts to copy my company software that has been in the public domain since 2005 at www.AxisPointe.com

Tags: prior-art, prior

In reference to the patent: [US20120239581](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120239581)

This patent seems to be a copy of my issued patent 20070033108 August 5, 2005 regarding the documentation of products and components in real property. There is no common use of the term "homogenous" in the construction and development industry as in claim 1.